# who Understand this C# opencl.net code?

Tags: c#, opencl

L want to learn the C# opencl.net to accelerate the code by gpu, this code is in the website https://habrahabr.ru/post/124873/, l cannot understand the meaning, anyone can explain it, and anywhere can l learn about the opencl.net, thank u very much.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Установка параметров, инициализирующих видеокарты при работе. В Platforms[1] должен стоять индекс
  //указывающий на используемую платформу
  ComputeContextPropertyList Properties = new ComputeContextPropertyList(ComputePlatform.Platforms[1]);
  ComputeContext Context = new ComputeContext(ComputeDeviceTypes.All, Properties, null, IntPtr.Zero);

  //Текст програмы, исполняющейся на устройстве (GPU или CPU). Именно эта программа будет выполнять паралельные
  //вычисления и будет складывать вектора. Программа написанна на языке, основанном на C99 специально под OpenCL.
  string vecSum = @" 
    __kernel void
    floatVectorSum(__global float * v1,
    __global float * v2)
    {
     int i = get_global_id(0);
     v1[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    }

    ";
  //Список устройств, для которых мы будем компилировать написанную в vecSum программу
  List<ComputeDevice> Devs = new List<ComputeDevice>();
  Devs.Add(ComputePlatform.Platforms[1].Devices[0]);
  Devs.Add(ComputePlatform.Platforms[1].Devices[1]);
  Devs.Add(ComputePlatform.Platforms[1].Devices[2]);
  //Компиляция программы из vecSum
  ComputeProgram prog = null;
  try
  {

    prog = new ComputeProgram(Context, vecSum); prog.Build(Devs, "", null, IntPtr.Zero);
  }

  catch

  { }

  //Инициализация новой программы
  ComputeKernel kernelVecSum = prog.CreateKernel("floatVectorSum");

  //Инициализация и присвоение векторов, которые мы будем складывать.
  float[] v1 = new float[100], v2 = new float[100];
  for (int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
  {
    v1[i] = i;
    v2[i] = 2 * i;
  } 
  //Загрузка данных в указатели для дальнейшего использования.
  ComputeBuffer<float> bufV1 = new ComputeBuffer<float>(Context, ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, v1);
  ComputeBuffer<float> bufV2 = new ComputeBuffer<float>(Context, ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, v2);
  //Объявляем какие данные будут использоваться в программе vecSum
  kernelVecSum.SetMemoryArgument(0, bufV1);
  kernelVecSum.SetMemoryArgument(1, bufV2);
  //Создание програмной очереди. Не забудте указать устройство, на котором будет исполняться программа!
  ComputeCommandQueue Queue = new ComputeCommandQueue(Context, Cloo.ComputePlatform.Platforms[1].Devices[0], Cloo.ComputeCommandQueueFlags.None);
  //Старт. Execute запускает программу-ядро vecSum указанное колличество раз (v1.Length)
  Queue.Execute(kernelVecSum, null, new long[] { v1.Length }, null, null);
  //Считывание данных из памяти устройства.
  float[] arrC = new float[100];
  GCHandle arrCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(arrC, GCHandleType.Pinned);
  Queue.Read<float>(bufV1, true, 0, 100, arrCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), null);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  ComputeContextPropertyList Properties = new ComputeContextPropertyList(ComputePlatform.Platforms[1]);
  ComputeContext Context = new ComputeContext(ComputeDeviceTypes.All, Properties, null, IntPtr.Zero);

  //define a function template that sum two vectors 
  string vecSum = @" 
    __kernel void
    floatVectorSum(__global float * v1,
    __global float * v2)
    {
     int i = get_global_id(0);
     v1[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    }

    ";
  //add gpu devices into list for executing the vecSum function defined at last step
  List<ComputeDevice> Devs = new List<ComputeDevice>();
  Devs.Add(ComputePlatform.Platforms[1].Devices[0]);
  Devs.Add(ComputePlatform.Platforms[1].Devices[1]);
  Devs.Add(ComputePlatform.Platforms[1].Devices[2]);
  //define a compute programe with function define and gpu devices specified.
  ComputeProgram prog = null;
  try
  {

    prog = new ComputeProgram(Context, vecSum); prog.Build(Devs, "", null, IntPtr.Zero);
  }


  catch

  { }


  ComputeKernel kernelVecSum = prog.CreateKernel("floatVectorSum");

  //init the vectors need by the vecSum.
  float[] v1 = new float[100], v2 = new float[100];
  for (int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
  {
    v1[i] = i;
    v2[i] = 2 * i;
  } 
  //create parametes needed as pass in parameter for vecSum.
  ComputeBuffer<float> bufV1 = new ComputeBuffer<float>(Context, ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, v1);
  ComputeBuffer<float> bufV2 = new ComputeBuffer<float>(Context, ComputeMemoryFlags.ReadWrite | ComputeMemoryFlags.UseHostPointer, v2);
  //pass the parameters in.
  kernelVecSum.SetMemoryArgument(0, bufV1);
  kernelVecSum.SetMemoryArgument(1, bufV2);
  //queue your compute request.
  ComputeCommandQueue Queue = new ComputeCommandQueue(Context, Cloo.ComputePlatform.Platforms[1].Devices[0], Cloo.ComputeCommandQueueFlags.None);
  //execute your compute request
  Queue.Execute(kernelVecSum, null, new long[] { v1.Length }, null, null);
  //clean the resource and read the result from the queue
  float[] arrC = new float[100];
  GCHandle arrCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(arrC, GCHandleType.Pinned);
  Queue.Read<float>(bufV1, true, 0, 100, arrCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), null);
 }
```

Comment: thank you very much! your answer is very useful to me.